# how change all fonts of a telerik control by one shot

Tags: jquery, css, fonts, telerik

please see the below css :

```
.RadGrid_Black,
.RadGrid_Black .rgMasterTable,
.RadGrid_Black .rgDetailTable,
.RadGrid_Black .rgGroupPanel table,
.RadGrid_Black .rgCommandRow table,
.RadGrid_Black .rgEditForm table,
.RadGrid_Black .rgPager table,
.GridToolTip_Black
{
    font:12px/16px "segoe ui",arial,sans-serif;
}
```

this css is one part of telerik RadGrid css.
i am looking for a way to change all fonts inside Telerik RadGrid or any other Telerik Control with jquery.
how can i do this job with jquery and overwrite all default fonts?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(functon() {
  $('body *').css({"font-family": "Comic Sans MS"});
})
```

This specific example will give your page a flashback to the 90's

To do it with CSS:

At the bottom of your last included stylesheet:

```
body * {
  font-family: "Comic Sans Ms" !important;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. thanks bro. (it worked) | but for my learning would u plz tell us how can we change all classes containing "Grid" in their names?

Comment: also is it possible to do this job -> "$('body *').css({"font-family": "Comic Sans MS"});" with only css (without using jquery)?

Comment: ok - really thanks - why this code does not work on my RadGrid ->             $('[class*="Grid"]').css({ "font-family": "Tahoma !important" });

Comment: Based on the CSS you provided, the font is not defined at the "RadGrid_Black" level, but rather at their children, which would override that code

Comment: By the way, that's three questions with three answers... Are there still more to go before I get Accepted Answer?

Comment: is not defined at the "RadGrid_Black" level -> but why? it has "Grid" string in it's name.also i put !important on that code!

Comment: i am so sorry bro, you are right. just help for the third q and i will accept ur answer.

Comment: The CSS you gave me there defines "RadGrid_Black", then it also defines all the children, which take precedence over the parent. That's all I can tell you with the code you've provided. .rgMasterTable, rgDetailTable, and then some other tables all defined as CHILDREN of RadGrid_Black have precedence. Your $('[class*="Grid"]').css({ "font-family": "Tahoma !important" }); only gets the parent element, not the children.

Comment: Really, this should all stay in CSS, I answered in jQuery because you asked in jQuery. But to fix your last one, you need to select all descending elements as well. $('[class*="Grid"], [class*="Grid"] *').css({ "font-family": "Tahoma !important" });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7367/discussion-between-kyle-macey-and-silverlight)